# smaller string gives bigger file size

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I am having a bit of a conundrum here... basically I am performing some very very basic file compression steps as follows:

1. open file and read as string/into a string
2. parse through the string, and replace repeating patterns with smaller size of text that represents the pattern (ex: aaaaaaaaaaa (11 chars) is replaced with [a#$%11] (8 chars))
3. save the new, smaller string, into a separate file (can compare sizes)

For some reason, even though the new string in memory is like, 3% smaller than the original string, when I save the string into a file, the file itself is BIGGER than the original file on the file system?? How is that even possible? If someone could explain that to me it would be great!

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
void bkg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string file = File.ReadAllText(this.txt_CompressFilename.Text);

            int olength = file.Length;
            int nlength = 0;
            decimal pct = 0;

            string lastchar = "";
            int count = 0;

            List<RepeatingPattern> SinglePatterns = new List<RepeatingPattern>();
            List<RepeatingPattern> DoublePatterns = new List<RepeatingPattern>();
            List<RepeatingPattern> TriplePatterns = new List<RepeatingPattern>();
            List<RepeatingPattern> QuadruplePatterns = new List<RepeatingPattern>();

            UpdateProgress("Read file contents", 0, 1, 6);
            UpdateProgress("Finding single character replacements.", pct, 1, 6);

            //single character replaces.
            for (int i = 0; i < olength; i++)
            {
                if (file[i].ToString() == lastchar)
                    count += 1;
                else
                {
                    //create a pattern, if the count is more than what a pattern's compressed pattern looks like to save space... 8 chars
                    //[a#$%#]
                    if (count > 7)
                    {
                        //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                        RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                        if (!SinglePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                            SinglePatterns.Add(ptn);
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    lastchar = file[i].ToString();
                }
            }

            //handle possible trailing pattern
            if (count > 7)
            {
                //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                if (!SinglePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                    SinglePatterns.Add(ptn);
            }

            if (SinglePatterns.Count > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < SinglePatterns.Count; i++)
                    file = file.Replace(SinglePatterns[i].ToString(), SinglePatterns[i].ToReplaceString());

            nlength = file.Length;
            pct = (decimal)(((double)(olength - nlength) / olength) * 100);

            UpdateProgress("Found and replaced " + SinglePatterns.Count, pct, 2, 6);
            UpdateProgress("Finding double character replacements.", pct, 2, 6);

            lastchar = "";
            count = 0;

            //double character replaces.
            for (int i = 0; i + 1 < file.Length; i = i + 2)
            {
                if ("" + file[i] + "" + file[i + 1] == lastchar)
                    count += 1;
                else
                {
                    //create a pattern, if the count is more than what a pattern's compressed pattern looks like to save space... 8 chars
                    //[aa#$%#]
                    if (count > 8)
                    {
                        //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                        RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                        if (!DoublePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                            DoublePatterns.Add(ptn);
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    lastchar = "" + file[i] + "" + file[i + 1];
                }
            }

            //handle possible trailing pattern
            if (count > 8)
            {
                //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                if (!DoublePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                    DoublePatterns.Add(ptn);
            }

            if (DoublePatterns.Count > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < DoublePatterns.Count; i++)
                    file = file.Replace(DoublePatterns[i].ToString(), DoublePatterns[i].ToReplaceString());

            nlength = file.Length;
            pct = (decimal)(((double)(olength - nlength) / olength) * 100);

            UpdateProgress("Found and replaced " + DoublePatterns.Count, pct, 3, 6);
            UpdateProgress("Finding triple character replacements.", pct, 3, 6);

            lastchar = "";
            count = 0;

            //triple character replaces.
            for (int i = 0; i + 2 < file.Length; i = i + 3)
            {
                if ("" + file[i] + "" + file[i + 1] + "" + file[i + 2] == lastchar)
                    count += 1;
                else
                {
                    //create a pattern, if the count is more than what a pattern's compressed pattern looks like to save space... 8 chars
                    //[aaa#$%#]
                    if (count > 9)
                    {
                        //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                        RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                        if (!TriplePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                            TriplePatterns.Add(ptn);
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    lastchar = "" + file[i] + "" + file[i + 1] + "" + file[i + 2];
                }
            }

            //handle possible trailing pattern
            if (count > 9)
            {
                //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                if (!TriplePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                    TriplePatterns.Add(ptn);
            }

            if (TriplePatterns.Count > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < TriplePatterns.Count; i++)
                    file = file.Replace(TriplePatterns[i].ToString(), TriplePatterns[i].ToReplaceString());

            nlength = file.Length;
            pct = (decimal)(((double)(olength - nlength) / olength) * 100);

            UpdateProgress("Found and replaced " + TriplePatterns.Count, pct, 4, 6);
            UpdateProgress("Finding quadruple character replacements.", pct, 4, 6);

            lastchar = "";
            count = 0;

            //triple character replaces.
            for (int i = 0; i + 3 < file.Length; i = i + 4)
            {
                if ("" + file[i] + "" + file[i + 1] + "" + file[i + 2] + "" + file[i + 3] == lastchar)
                    count += 1;
                else
                {
                    //create a pattern, if the count is more than what a pattern's compressed pattern looks like to save space... 8 chars
                    //[aaaa#$%#]
                    if (count > 10)
                    {
                        //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                        RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                        if (!QuadruplePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                            QuadruplePatterns.Add(ptn);
                    }
                    count = 0;
                    lastchar = "" + file[i] + "" + file[i + 1] + "" + file[i + 2] + "" + file[i + 3];
                }
            }

            //Handle possible trailing pattern
            if (count > 10)
            {
                //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
                RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
                if (!QuadruplePatterns.Contains(ptn))
                    QuadruplePatterns.Add(ptn);
            }

            if (QuadruplePatterns.Count > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < QuadruplePatterns.Count; i++)
                    file = file.Replace(QuadruplePatterns[i].ToString(), QuadruplePatterns[i].ToReplaceString());

            nlength = file.Length;
            pct = (decimal)(((double)(olength - nlength) / olength) * 100);

            UpdateProgress("Found and replaced " + QuadruplePatterns.Count, pct, 5, 6);
            UpdateProgress("Saving new .cmp file...", pct, 5, 6);

            string newpath = this.txt_FolderName.Text + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(this.txt_CompressFilename.Text);
            newpath = newpath.Substring(0, newpath.LastIndexOf("."));
            newpath = newpath + ".cmp";
            File.WriteAllText(newpath, file);

            stopwatch.Stop();

            UpdateProgress("Compression completed! Time to compress file: " + string.Format("{0}", stopwatch.Elapsed), pct, 6, 6);
            string report = "Compression report\n\n";

            FileInfo inf = new FileInfo(this.txt_CompressFilename.Text);
            FileInfo infNew = new FileInfo(newpath);
            report += "Single character replacements made: " + SinglePatterns.Count + "\n\n";
            report += "Double character replacements made: " + DoublePatterns.Count + "\n\n";
            report += "Triple character replacements made: " + TriplePatterns.Count + "\n\n";
            report += "Quadruple character replacements made: " + QuadruplePatterns.Count + "\n\n";
            report += "Total compression ration achieved in string: " + pct + "% \n\n";
            report += "Old file size: " + inf.Length + "\nNew file size: " + infNew.Length + " in bytes.";

            report += "Total time to achieve compression: " + string.Format("{0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
            e.Result = report;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            e.Result = ex;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for the RepeatingPattern class...

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Compressor
{
    public class RepeatingPattern : IEquatable<RepeatingPattern>
    {
        public string RepeatingChar { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

        public RepeatingPattern()
        {
            this.RepeatingChar = "";
            this.Count = -1;
        }

        public RepeatingPattern(string rchar, int count)
        {
            this.RepeatingChar = rchar;
            this.Count = count;
        }

        public RepeatingPattern(string FromReplaceString)
        {

            FromReplaceString = FromReplaceString.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");

            List<string> parts = FromReplaceString.Split(new string[] { "#$%" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();

            if (parts.Count != 2)
                throw new ArgumentException("Invalid argument count. Must be in this format: [a#$%N]");

            try
            {
                this.RepeatingChar = parts[0];
                this.Count = int.Parse(parts[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to cast the argument and create an object from it. Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            RepeatingPattern tmp = obj as RepeatingPattern;
            if (tmp != null)
                return base.Equals(tmp);
            else
                throw new Exception("Invalid comparison type. Both objects must be of type RepeatingPattern");
        }

        public bool Equals(RepeatingPattern tmp)
        {
            return this.RepeatingChar == tmp.RepeatingChar && this.Count == tmp.Count;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.RepeatingChar.GetHashCode() ^ this.Count.GetHashCode();
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string retval = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
                retval += this.RepeatingChar;

            return retval;
        }

        public string ToReplaceString()
        {
            return "[" + this.RepeatingChar + "#$%" + this.Count + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would help if we could see the code you're using.  I don't think we can help without seeing your code.

Comment: Have you had a look at the file content? Does it contain what you expect? Maybe you appended to the file rather than writing it from scratch

Comment: It depends from Encoding, in case of ASCI, the file size will be smaller because each symbol in ASCI is exactly 1 byte... but UTF-8 for example is tricky, some symbols are 1 byte there, while the others can be more...

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan ok... so if I save the new string with the same encoding as the original file, then it should technically be smaller?

Comment: Is aaaaaaaaaaa the actual content of the file, or is it just an example? Note that compressing `abcdef` **will** result in a larger file `a#$%1b#$%1c#$%1d#$%1e#$%1f#$%1`

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv, No... assume first file encoding is UTF-8, you replace char 'a' which is 1 byte with char '#' which is more (just an example, google for exact sizes)... than, despite the fact you replace 1 symbol to another, file size can be more .. check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: There's probably no need for all those special characters. Have a look at [Run Length Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Comment: @ThomasWeller as you can see from the code I posted... it only replaces character repeating patterns that would result in a smaller footprint than the original pattern to be replaced...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp this is exactly what I am trying to achieve!! in my own way of course... i need the special chars to delimit my compression patterns from the original content... but yes! This is basically what I am trying to do on my own/from scratch sorta deal... ;)

Comment: @Amy thanks! I don't know why everyone is downvoting this question though... it feels very accurate and "on-topic"... i mean... a smaller string gives a bigger footprint is not something "dumb" or "that makes no sens" IMHO... but whatever...

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv The concept isn't what's getting voted down. It's the content of the question. RLE is a well-known and widely used mechanism. As a programming Q&A site, we expect you to be asking why your implementation isn't working which means we needed your code to help.

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv People can downvote for a variety of reasons.  Keep in mind that the primary goal of SO is to produce high-quality questions and answers that provide long-term value.  I wouldn't take it personally.  Right now, the code in the question isn't something we can simply copy into a console app, so it takes more work for us to analyze it.  We've also got a lot of comments here clarifying the question and analyzing the code; those comments can be incorporated into the question itself to keep everything in one spot, making it easier for others to follow.

Comment: You're not doing yourself any favors by modifying the `file` variable in-place, so to speak. It would be much cleaner, in my humble opinion, if you generated a new, compressed output in its own variable. Anyway, to see if it's the save that causes the size to grow check what `file.Length` returns before saving it out.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I have made an attempt at the code. Some differences:

- I made a helper function to find runs in the text
- I build a new string (using `StringBuilder`) as I go through the old string instead of replacing in the old string

I think my code is a bit simpler than yours. I have tested with:

```
Input:  "aaaaaaaaaaabbbcdcdcdcdcdcdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxhello"
Output: "[a#$%11]bbb[cd#$%6][x#$%18]hello"
```

Here's the code. This is a first draft. Probably lots of improvements to make:

```
static int FindRun(string s, int start, int length)
{
    if (start + length >= s.Length) return 0;

    int numRuns = 0;
    string pattern = s.Substring(start, length);
    for (int i = start + length; i <= s.Length - length; i += length)
    {
        if (s.Substring(i, length) == pattern) numRuns += 1;
        else break;
    }
    return numRuns;
}

static string EncodeString(string src)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
    {
        string theRun = null;
        int numRuns = 0;
        // Find runs of lengths 4, 3, 2, 1
        for (int j = 4; j >= 1; j--)
        {
            int runs = FindRun(src, i, j);
            if (runs > 1)  // Run found!
            {
                // Save it for later. Want to append the longest run
                theRun = src.Substring(i, j);
                numRuns = runs;
            }
        }
        // No run? Just append the letter
        if (theRun == null)
        {
            sb.Append(src[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            // This is the size of the run
            int replacementStringSize = (numRuns * theRun.Length) + (theRun.Length - 1);
            // This is the code to use as a replacement
            String runCode = String.Format("[{0}#$%{1}]", theRun, numRuns + 1);
            // Only append if the code length is smaller than the original run
            if (runCode.Length < replacementStringSize)
            {
                sb.Append(runCode);
            }
            else
            {
                // Don't encode. Put original run back
                for (int j = 0; j <= numRuns; j++)
                {
                    sb.Append(theRun);
                }
            }
            // Skip over the run
            i += replacementStringSize;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: But does it solve the OP's question of is the new version bigger/smaller and why is the new version in their's bigger?

Comment: @gilliduck No. I had trouble following OP's code. I put this here just to give them an alternative. They can take it or leave it. But sometimes it is helpful to see a different perspective.

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the much larger output files is because of encoding.  ChromeSetup.exe is 1,397,976 bytes.  When the file is read in using `File.ReadAllText` it attempts to detect the string encoding.  The string is 1,327,384 characters long in this case.  Here's the key though, because of encoding each character isn't necessarily a single byte.  For example in UTF-8 each character is 1 to 4 bytes.  So then when the result string is written out a single character could become multiple bytes.

For reading/writing executables/binary files you're better off using `File.ReadAllBytes()``File.WriteAllBytes()`.

While attempting to run your code I came across several other bugs.  Here are the bugs I found.

1) In the double/triple/quad character replaces the for loop bounds should check up to the character that will be used.

```
//double character replaces.
for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i = i + 2)
{
  if ("" + file[i] + "" + file[i + 1] == lastchar)
```

This will cause an out of index exception if the file string is an odd number of characters.  Add in a `+ 1` to fix this.

```
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < file.Length; i = i + 2)
```

For the triple this will be `+ 2`, for quad `+ 3`.

2) If the string ends with a repeating pattern this isn't handled correctly.  In the for loops the pattern count is only checked when a different char is encountered.  So if the pattern is at the end of the string it isn't detected.  You could handle this by checking the count after the for loop.

```
if (count > 7)
{
    //create and add a pattern to the list if necessary.
    RepeatingPattern ptn = new RepeatingPattern(lastchar.ToString(), count);
    if (!SinglePatterns.Contains(ptn))
      SinglePatterns.Add(ptn);
}
```

3) `count` and `lastchar` should be reset before each for loop.  If one for loop ends with `count = 17` and the next for loop runs it would add a repeating pattern of count 17, which has already been replaced.

4) As others have mentioned, doing replacements in your input string as you go along has the potential to cause issues.

If you can post your `RepeatingPattern` code and your input text file we can run down the exact cause of your larger output file.

**Edit:** Running with your RepeatingPattern code I see another small bug.  The pattern "aaaaaaaaaa" becomes "[a#$%9]a". it should be replacing one more character.  This could be making your output string slightly longer than expected.  To fix this, in the replacement for loops set `count` to 1 (instead of 0) when a new pattern is started.

Comment: Thanks those are great catches! I have updated the original code to account for all of this, and updated it in the question, and I have added the RepeatingPattern code as well.

Comment: and yes... the resulting string contains what I am expecting, and in memory, is actually around 3% smaller in size than the original read size...

Comment: So did that fix it, or is the output file still larger?

Comment: sadly no... did not fix any of the size issues... "new" file is twice the size of original almost (from 1.10 megs to 2.0)... it must be the whole encoding thing, and that the split chars i'm using account for more bytes?

Comment: Yeah probably. See my last edit, that might help slightly.  Can you post your input file so I can run with the same input?

Comment: @MaxOvrdrv Careful about updating code in the question in response to answers.  If the updates alter the function and meaning of the code, it can render the answers you've received obsolete, *potentially* annoying folks.  That doesn't seem to be the case here, I just want you to be aware for the future.  I've seen it happen before with unfortunate results.

Comment: @gunnerone thanks... and yes: actually the one I am using now (as of now), is the current Google Chrome installer exe file... which can be found on their website. (ChromeSetup.exe)